# Restart Azure web app (aspnet5 rc1-final) deployed using Appveyor

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, appveyor

I'm using Appveyor to deploy my aspnet5 (rc1-final) site to an Azure web app (site) using Web deploy. The deployment step works fine but I need to restart the site manually using the Azure portal and that is pretty annoying.

What I have read is that the web app does not restart automatically?

I have tried to use powershell to restart the site but it doesn't seem to work, or I'm doing something wrong?

This is the powershell script I use atm.

```
after_deploy:
 - ps: Disable-AzureDataCollection
 - ps: Select-AzureSubscription -Current -SubscriptionName "Visual Studio Premium with MSDN"
 - ps: Restart-AzureWebsite -Name "sitename"
```

I tried using just `- ps: Restart-AzureWebsite -Name "sitename"` but Azure complained about the subscription name so I added that.
I'm using Visual Studio Premium with MSDN it's pretty obvious that it does not work as subscription name?

```
Select-AzureSubscription : The subscription name Visual Studio Premium with MSDN doesn't exist.
```

Is it possible to restart the site using powershell or is this a dead end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the old PowerShell CmdLets. Please [install](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/) the latest, which is currently 1.0.1.

With the latest, the CmdLet you want to run is:

```
Restart-AzureRmWebApp YourResourceGroup YourWebApp
```

As for authentication from a CI server, the recommended approach is to use a Service Principal. See [this post](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/12/azure-service-principal.html) for details.

Comment: Oh, I really hope that the Azure team makes some changes in the future so the site restarts automatically when a new version is deployed. Thanks though ...

Comment: The site should pick up changes as soon as they're deployed. However, your question was primarily about how to force a restart via PowerShell, and this is what I answered. Please avoid asking two separate questions at once ('should it restart automatically' and 'how do I call PowerShell), as that can cause confusion. This should have been two separate questions.

Comment: I see, I'm sorry for that and thank you for your help!

Comment: @DavidEbbo I think the whole purpose of this question is that sometimes Web Deploy throws `Web Deploy cannot modify the file 'X' on the destination because it is locked by an external process.` message while syncing ASP.NET 5 app to Azure Web App and usually people claim it won't happen when publishing from Visual Studio IDE (however, seems like it's not always the case: [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/694) and [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/141)). Does Visual Studio do something else besides just syncing folder with `IisApp` provider?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to connect to your Azure subscription named 'Visual Studio Premium with MSDN' - I very much doubt this is your subscription.

List out subscriptions you are authorised to:
`Get-AzureSubscription`

Find the name of the one you wish to deploy to and change to:

```
 Select-AzureSubscription -Current -SubscriptionName "<Correct name here>"
```

Comment: Not trollin', but (one) of my sub's is (literally) called that :) I just _added_ some custom text, to the end of it...

Comment: I thought that when the label says "Subscription name", it's really the subscription name... http://cl.ly/e4PO

I'll see if I can get hold of the "other" subscription name

Comment: I suppose it is possible. I always use Subscription IDs rather than names.

Comment: Yes, that was the correct subscription name and all my commands works great from my powershell command line but not in Appveyor. Maybe there is problems running commands `after_deploy:`?